# Why use smartpointers?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

When in particular are smart pointers good to use, and why use a smart pointer anyway if pointers in C++ are discouraged to use? As an example:

```
class Object {  }

smart_pointer < Object > pInstance;
//wherein I can use the very simple way
Object instance;
```

Comment: "pointers in C++ are discouraged to use". Well, how would polymorphism work if you can't use pointers ? Pointers are needed, smart pointers make pointer's use safer/easier/better.

Comment: Use pointers only if you have to. And when you do, try to use smart pointers instead of raw ones.

Comment: When attaching a code sample, attach a valid code at least.

Comment: @JBL Can you give a link explaining how pointers work with what you said? I am very new to programming.

Comment: Unfortunately statically allocated objects, while being the preferred and default way, are not sufficient in all cases, like situations with hard to define object lifetime (not directly bound to the lifetime of a function call or another object), or when the need for dynamic polymorphism arises. And in those cases dynamic memory allocation is often the best way to solve it, and made much more easy and safe through smart pointers.

Comment: I was wondering if all the users up voted JBL are the ones that down voted me

Comment: @user2477739 Don't know if there is a better reference, but [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) could help. Prerequisites : you must know how pointers, classes and inheritance work.

Comment: @JBL As I understand in the link, is it that.. it is useful only for instantiating the (abstract) base class and you cannot decide first what would it be. For example, `smart_pointer<Abstract_Base_Object> unkown_Obj;` then I can make this any object as long as this base class is derived in that `class`?? Am I right? So I can sit again peacefully.

Comment: No, it is not "only" useful for that. Pointers work this way. I'm making a more thorough answer at the moment, it'll explain it.

Comment: @JBL okay, hope that I will understand it thorough also

Comment: Downvotes are the sign that something might be wrong with your question; they are by no means personal or meant to discourage you. You might want to review FAQ and About pages, to ensure your question is OK.

Comment: @JBL, you could just use references, but point still taken :P

Answer (score 5):

Smart pointers are good when you need to maintain ownership of an object. Using them will ensure proper destruction. When pointer is treated as a reference, using smart pointer **can sometimes** be worse (for example, in terms of performance).

Pointers are an essential part of C++, but using them got much easier as smart ones in C++11 with move semantics introduced (which essentially made `unique_ptr` possible). That's why in modern code you should always use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` if available.

---

Edit: You asked for an example, where a pointer could be beneficial to use. The most common problem that I can think of is an optional component of some system. This component will use a lot of memory, so you don't want to always allocate it, neither you control its allocations (so it can't be in "empty" state itself, i.e. is not nullable). Boost.Optional and C++14-ish `std::optional` allocate memory of the POD-ish size of T, so they won't do. Using a pointer you can optionally allocate that memory:

```
class Outer { 
    std::unique_ptr<BigInner> optionalComponent;
public:
    void initializeOptionalComponent() { 
        optionalComponent = new BigInner();
    }
    void useOptionalComponent() {
        if (!optionalComponent)
            // handle the error
        // operate
    } 
};
```

That will solve the problem, but will introduce the obvious, *another* problem: optionalComponent can be null, which requires all functions using it to check for valid state at all times. Had it been a plain by-value member, it would (or at least should) be always in *valid* state. As such, if you don't need a pointer, *don't use it at all*, use `vector<MyClass>` and plain members.

Anyway, using smart pointer in this case allows you to keep the Rule of Zero; you don't have to write destructor, copy constructor or assignment operator, and the class will behave safely.

Comment: Can you give me an example wherein I should wrap the object with smart pointer or not. As in my example above.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer : smart pointers are useful for (notably)

- Enforcing [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)
- Managing pointers ownership

**Enforcing RAII**

One problem that comes with pointers and cause (in many way, some obvious, some twisted) crashes in your program is that you are responsible for the memory underneath them. That means that when you allocate memory dynamically (through `new`), you are responsible for this memory, and must not forget to call `delete`. That means it will happen, and worse, there are case where even if you didn't forget, the delete statement will never be reached.
Consider this code :

```
void function(){
    MyClass* var = new MyClass;

    //Do something

    delete var;
}
```

Now, if this function throw an exception before the delete statement is reached, the pointer will not be deleted... Memory leak !

RAII is a way to avoid this :

```
void function(){
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> var(new MyClass);

    //Do something

    //No need to delete anything
}
```

The pointer is held by an object, and deleted in its destructor. The difference with the previous code is that, if the function throw an exception, *the destructor of the shared pointer will be called* and the pointers will thus be deleted, avoiding a memory leak.

RAII takes advantages of the fact that when a local variable goes out of scope, its dtor is called.

**Managing pointers ownership**

Note which smart pointer I used in the previous example. The [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is a smart pointer that is useful when you pass pointers around. If many part of your code need a pointer to the same object, it can be tricky to decide where it should be deleted. You might want to delete the pointer somewhere, but what if another part of your code is using it ? It results in an access to a deleted pointer, which is not desirable at all ! `std::shared_ptr` helps prevent this. When you pass a shared_ptr around, it keeps track of how many part of the code have a reference to it. When there isn't any reference to the pointer anymore, this pointer deletes the memory. In other terms *when nobody uses the pointer anymore, it is safely deleted*.

There are other kind of smart pointers that address other issue, like `std::unique_ptr` which provide a pointer that is the only owner of the pointer underneath it.

*Note - Small explanation on polymorphism*

You *need* pointers to use polymorphism. If you have an abstract class `MyAbstract` (that means, it have at least one virtual, say `doVirtual()`), it cannot be instantiated. The following code :

```
MyAbstract var;
```

won't compile, you'll get something along the line of `Can't instantiate abstract class` from your compiler.

But this is legal (with both `ImplA` and `ImplB` inheriting publicly from `MyAbstract`:

```
MyAbstract* varA = new ImplA;
MyAbstract* varB = new ImplB;

varA->doVirtual(); //Will call ImplA implementation
varB->doVirtual(); //Will call ImplB implementation

delete varA;
delete varB;
```